# loop over variable names in R and do a tabulation of the variable within the loop

Tags: r

I have a data set with some categorical variables, say "x", "y", "z". I want to do a loop and tabulate each of the variables of the data set. Let's say the name of the data set is "df". I know a package named "tidyverse" and I can use the following codes to get the stats I need after loading this package:

```
df %>% count(x)
df %>% count(y)
df %>% count(z)
```

But instead of typing these similar codes 3 times, I want to do it via loop. I tried to do it like this,

```
varnames <- c("x", "y", "z")

for (i in 1:length(varnames)) {
  df %>% count(varnames[i])
}
```

But it didn't show me anything. I was expecting same returns as typing the codes 3 times respectively. Does anyone know what's wrong with the loop above or how to do this, i.e. loop over a list of variable names and refer the variable within the loop and generate some stats.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

following should do the trick

```
lapply(df,table)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just tried. It works. But is there a way to do it via loop? I want to make it more general, not just for this specific case - i.e. if I want to do similar things for a set of variables of a data set (assume there is no direct function, like "table", that I can use in "lapply()"), how can I loop over the variables and refer to the corresponding variable within each loop and do the things I want to do on this variable?